# App we create in titanium studio, it should be there in Myapps?

Tags: titanium

I am using titanium studio to create app with push notification, I am using GCM and i have API key and Sender ID.

Now is i have to configure for push notification, for that i have to go to Myapps and do configuration work there, but i could not find My app.

When we create new app in titanium studio, it should show in Myapps  https://my.appcelerator.com/apps , But it is not there.

What is that I am missing here ?

Comment: Have you enabled Cloud in your application?

Comment: yes... and i have added ti.cloud and ti.cloudpush in tiapp.xml